# xCode - How to tell whether something will be deprecated?

Tags: ios, xcode, deprecated

Is it a folly to try to future-proof an app? By accident, I came across statements today that will be deprecated.

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This made me wonder if there is some list of methods to avoid/change.

Comment: @CodaFi - UIViewController documentation for those methods.  I'm a bit behind on versions, but what I read is pointing to using the methods with completion blocks instead.

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have said. I was checking the syntax on these, and happened to see in the online docs that they are inline to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I know of, you may hear something on Apple dev forum speaking of the next version of iOs but you really can't speak aout ... everything is under NDA

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll close this out but I did find that the release notes for xCode betas do show what's in and out. That's a help, even if there is limited time to adapt an app.

Answer (score 1):

There's no clear way to tell if some API, function, class, etc... will be deprecated in the future.

You can however follow the developer community. You can also take an educated guess by checking if the style, naming, functionality differ significantly enough from the rest of the API, class, project, etc.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I don't know how to follow the community without getting deluged with email - often not very interesting. Do you have a suggested community where people stay on topic? The Apple Dev forums are great, but unless you subscribe all over the place, you cannot keep up..